# Application testing with Office365 using Azure AD

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory, office365, shibboleth

I'm trying to test my application with Office365 SSO. Since this is the test app, I don't have AD installed on my machine (and unable to use corporate AD either). My application only supports Shibboleth connection.

I've got a default domain on Azure services which I would like to use for my tests. Is is possible to configure Shibboleth SP against Azure AD without setting up test Windows AD on my virtual machine? Unfortunately, all the information I could find refers to local AD setup and synchronization with Azure services.

Below is the summary of my current setup:

- local instance of Shibboleth SP
- Active Azure AD test domain

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The Azure AD tenant isn't analogous to a traditional AD domain at all. What exactly are you trying to test here?

Comment: @BrianDesmond, I'm trying to test SSO using Shibboleth

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to federate Shib with O365 and validate authentication as-if someone is coming from your AD with domain credentials, you need to stand up a domain controller as a VM or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'm creating a test domain controller to work with O365